# Как выполнить Overriding в примере? И стоит ли вообще

Tags: java, оптимизация, методы, override

У меня десяток методов с похожими функциями. Стоит ли для оптимизации перегружать десять методов от одного? И если да, подскажите верный способ выполнения задачи. Буду очень благодарен.
На примере два метода:

```
class Data {
int[] data_serv, data_var;

  /* ------------SERVICE------------ */
  void ServiceArray(int size){
      data_serv = new int[size];
      for(int i = 0; i < data_serv.length; i++){
          data_serv[i] = i + 1;
      }
  }


  /* ------------VARIATION------------ */
  void VariationArray(int size){
      data_var = new int[size];
      for(int i = 0; i < data_var.length; i++){
          data_var[i] = i + 1;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ваш пример из вашей конкретной задачи? Или это абстрактный пример?

Comment: вырезана часть из практической моей работы.

Comment: А не проще ли сделать один метод, который возвращает ссылку на массив?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не стоит, достаточно создать метод и передать ему необходимое количество параметров

```
class Data {
  int[] data_serv, data_var;

  private void initArray(int[] data, int size){
      data = new int[size];
      for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          data[i] = i + 1;
      }
  }

  /* ------------SERVICE------------ */
  void ServiceArray(int size){
     initArray(data_serv, size);
  }


  /* ------------VARIATION------------ */
  void VariationArray(int size){
     initArray(data_var, size);
  }
}
```

Comment: По моему, оно не передаёт данные массивам (`int[] data_serv, data_var;`). Т.к. при вызове с другого класса этих ссылок - выдаёт: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Input.service_id` в Input.service_id указан код с работой этого массива.
@Roman C